# Apex CALLOUT_REQUEST is failing with System.CalloutException: Read timed out

Tags: callout, httprequest, timeout

Our endpoint is an https request.

> |CALLOUT_REQUEST|[217]|System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=https:[intentionally left off]

The logs show:

> |EXCEPTION_THROWN|[217]|System.CalloutException: Read timed out

We have already tested the https request externally from Salesforce and determined that 21/24 requests will fail with a timeout of 10 seconds.  As the time taken varies from 10 seconds to 18 seconds.

We are thinking of increasing the timeout to 20 seconds by setting a custom timeout in Apex.   The default timeout is 10 seconds as I understand it.

Would this work?

Comment: As per doc you can set upto 120,000 milliseconds (or) 120 seconds for your custom timeout value. If timeout is the reason for the calloutexception you may give it a try by adjusting the timeout using settimeout() https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_timeouts.htm